# How to make a copy of xml tree in python using ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm using  xml.etree.ElementTree to parse xml file. I'm parsing xml file in the following way:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(options.xmlfile)
root = tree.getroot()
```

This is my xml file:

```
<rootElement>
    <member>
        <member_id>439854395435</member_id>
    </member>
</rootElement>
```

Then I'm saving it:

```
tree.write(options.outcsvfile)
```

How can I make a copy of my tree to produce something like this:

```
<rootElement>
    <member>
        <member_id>439854395435</member_id>
    </member>
    <member>
        <member_id>439854395435</member_id>
    </member>
</rootElement>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a copy of the `member` element and append it. Example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import copy

tree = ET.parse("test.xml")
root = tree.getroot() 

# Find element to copy 
member1 = tree.find("member")

# Create a copy
member2 = copy.deepcopy(member1)

# Append the copy 
root.append(member2)

print ET.tostring(root)
```

Output:

```
<rootElement>
    <member>
        <member_id>439854395435</member_id>
    </member>
<member>
        <member_id>439854395435</member_id>
    </member>
</rootElement>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Update for Python 3.9

As of Python 3.9, `ElementTree` has an [`indent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.indent) function, which will make the document look a little cleaner.  The default is to indent each level with two spaces, but adding the `, space='    '` parameter, the original 4-space indentation can be replicated.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import copy

tree = ET.parse("test.xml")
root = tree.getroot() 

# Find element to copy 
member1 = tree.find("member")

# Create a copy
member2 = copy.deepcopy(member1)

# Append the copy 
root.append(member2)

ET.indent(root, space='    ')          # <-- New

ET.dump(root)
```

Output:

```xml
<rootElement>
    <member>
        <member_id>439854395435</member_id>
    </member>
    <member>
        <member_id>439854395435</member_id>
    </member>
</rootElement>
```