# Python: How to copy and insert a xml element at a specific location

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree

I'm using xml.etree.ElementTree to parse XML-files. I would now like to 
copy a specific XML element and insert it at my desired destination.

What the XML-file basically looks like:

```
<file>
   <page id="1">
      <text id="1"> sample text </text>
      <text id="2"> sample text II </text>
   </page>
   <page id="2">
      <text id="1"> sample text copy</text>
      <text id="2"> sample text me </text>
   </page>
   <page id="3">
      <text id="1"> sample text hello </text>
      <text id="2"> sample text world </text>
   </page>
   <page id="4">
      <text id="1"> sample text game </text>
      <text id="2"> sample text over </text>
   </page>
</file>
```

For example, I want to copy the page-element where id="2" and insert it after the page-element where id="3". Additionally, I want to change the id of the new element.

What the result should look like:

```
<file>
   <page id="1">
      <text id="1"> sample text </text>
      <text id="2"> sample text II </text>
   </page>
   <page id="2">
      <text id="1"> sample text copy</text>
      <text id="2"> sample text me </text>
   </page>
   <page id="3">
      <text id="1"> sample text hello </text>
      <text id="2"> sample text world </text>
   </page>
   *<page id="2.1">
      <text id="1"> sample text copy</text>
      <text id="2"> sample text me </text>
   </page>*
   <page id="4">
      <text id="1"> sample text game </text>
      <text id="2"> sample text over </text>
   </page>
</file>
```

*the inserted element

I've already tried some variations of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906104/how-to-make-a-copy-of-xml-tree-in-python-using-elementtree?rq=1), but I always had issues with the attributes (in this case the id).
Currently I'm using xml.etree.ElementTree and it would be great if someone can help me solving my problem with this package, but I take every package that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find a specific node, use find() with some XPath to get the page node with id=2:

```
# Find element to copy
member1 = root.find(".//page[@id='2']")

# Create copy
member2 = copy.deepcopy(member1)
```

To change the value of the id attribute, use :

```
member2.set('id' , '2.1')
```

Now you can insert the new element as the 4th element. For this use insert instead of the append used in the answer you linked.

```
root.insert(3, member2)
```

The output is:

```
<file>
   <page id="1">
      <text id="1"> sample text </text>
      <text id="2"> sample text II </text>
   </page>
   <page id="2">
      <text id="1"> sample text copy</text>
      <text id="2"> sample text me </text>
   </page>
   <page id="3">
      <text id="1"> sample text hello </text>
      <text id="2"> sample text world </text>
   </page>
   <page id="2.1">
      <text id="1"> sample text copy</text>
      <text id="2"> sample text me </text>
   </page>
   <page id="4">
      <text id="1"> sample text game </text>
      <text id="2"> sample text over </text>
   </page>
</file>
```