# How to duplicate a node in xml.etree?

Tags: python, elementtree

I'm using `xml.etree` module to parse an `xml` file.

While handling the Element Tree, I need to operate on a node in it, without changing the data stored in the tree. Hence I want to duplicate the node.

To be more specific, let's say there is a node `a`, and I need to duplicate it into `b`, such that when I operate on `b`, like changing its attribution, the data in `a` won't be change.

Is there any api that can do this?

I know maybe I can copy the element recursively, but I want a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: There is a `copy` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html. For an example involving ElementTree, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38913589/407651

Comment: Thanks a lot. `deepcopy` is really a quite useful function.